# Sending data from multiple HTML form using JQuery ajax

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

Hello I  just starting learning jquery ajax  to  upload file.

I'm  using simple html form here and embedding javascript/jquery code in it 
to perform ajax request.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html>
<head>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='jquery-2.1.3.min.js'></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id='entryform' method="">
        <input id='formText' type='text' name='text'><br>
        <input id='formFile' type='file' name='file'>
    </form>
    <div id='fill'></div>
</body>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#entryform').change(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                url : 'ajax.php',
                data : new FormData(this),
                processData : false,
                contentType : false,
                type : 'POST',
                success : function (retval){
                    $('#fill').html(retval);
                } 
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

And this is the PHP code for process :

```
<?php 

$updir = 'images/';

move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $updir.$_FILES['file']['name']);

//echo $updir._FILES['file']['name'];
echo "<img src='".$updir.$_FILES['file']['name']."'>";
```

I the above code i'm trying to upload an image without reloading the page
and show the image to the immadiately after the image has been uploaded.

But when i'm trying to run the code, I'm getting a weird behaviour, that is when
entering the input to text form the value from the text form that was newly entered is showing immediately.

I mean I want the form file is showed immediately to the user when uploading done not the form text.

Any idea how to fix this? without omitting the text form ?

Comment: what is the problem exactly? it is quite unclear

Comment: The proble is when I try to input some value to the form 
the first form, that is the text form immediately showing it's value,
All i want is just the second form, that is the file form, showing it's image 
value immediately after upload.

Comment: if you give correct $updir path in img tag then image will be displayed corretly, from your code im getting broken image, im not getting ant text

Comment: I mean here, i bind the change event handler to the form by using the form id. And that is why that's why the text form get the same behaviour with the file form.My question is hot to separate this behaviour ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you need to add the `Event handler` to formFile so this will help you.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#formFile').change(function (e) {
        var myfiles = $(this).get(0);
        var files = myfiles.files;
        var data = new FormData();
        for (i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
            data.append('file', files[i]);
        }
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url : 'ajax.php',
            data : data,
            processData : false,
            contentType : false,
            type : 'POST',
            success : function (retval) {
                $('#fill').html(retval);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Can you explain me why adding event handler to `formFile` instead of
to `entryform`?